# Mobile Data Analysis in Excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis, excel-2016

I collected the mobile data consumption using DATA USAGE in android. Spread over days of the weeks (Monday to Sunday), I want to analyse two apps i.e. Facebook and Messenger, to check whether there was a significant data usage difference depending on the days of the weeks. Should I be using t-test or some other method? What's the best method that can be used in excel to analyse this.

P.s. Help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

If you believe your data is normally distributed then statistically speaking it sounds like you're going to want to use the t-test method. You don't know the population's standard deviation so that would be my choice. However, this data should be taken over at least 30 weeks if you want the data for each weekday to be somewhat accurate.

Comment: If you're comparing two samples you'll also have to see if the SDs between the two samples are the same because you run a t test.